# Prevent mobile users from downloading desktop carousel images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like a static background image to become a carousel at a certain (desktop-ish) breakpoint. Would it be possible for me to prevent the mobile user from downloading those carousel images? As far as I'm aware a media query won't be enough here.

I'm not referring to the user manually downloading the images to save to their device, I mean their browser doing so automatically.

Comment: what exactly have you tried?  please include your code.

Comment: I have a background image which becomes a carousel at a certain browser width. I have an event listener on window size which runs the carousel function once it reaches a specific width. This to my knowledge is not enough to prevent the user downloading all the images.

Comment: Once the browser gets the HTML source, there's no stopping it from downloading the images. You'll need to modify your page to not have it by default, and then use JS with AJAX to download the appropriate section. Keep in mind that DPI, along with resolution is important.

Comment: @David AJAX. That makes sense. I'd like to accept this as the answer but I can't as it's a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @user3669771 There is no reason to use AJAX. Your JS code that monitors the browser width along with the Media Query i posted will do the trick.

Comment: @David Media Queries allow you to conditionally set the source, so only the appropriate file is delivered. AJAX is overkill here.

Comment: @user3669771 Scott has a good answer. I didn't thing of doing it that way, but essentially, big enough = real background image, small enough = no background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** will perfectly solve this issue.

```
/* Mobile-first */
element {
   background-image:url("small image here");
}


/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

  element {
     background-image:url("large image here");
  }
}
```

If you use this code and have your browser at a size greater than 1024px and using the developer tools, inspect the element, you will see the large version of the image being used as the source for the background. If you then shrink your browser below 1024, you will see the source change to the small version. Browsers will only download the value of the source for the image, so a mobile user will never wind up downloading the large version.

Comment: You might want to add a paragraph on how to use this with the actual carousal. E.g. used IDs for each image, and what-not.

Comment: @David The question was not about how implement the carousel (of which there are countless ways). The OP seems to already have that working.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Interesting. I didn't realise this was all that was needed! Thanks.

Comment: @user3669771 You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but future readers with limited experience may not understand how to expand what you put. If they're just starting out, and trying to modify something (as many do), this answer may look like it's only for one image.

Comment: @David That's not the way SO works. Someone looking to build a carousel would post a question as such. Answers should stay on point and be as concise as possible for future readers. There are multitudes of ways to build carousels, so providing a random one here wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I didn't say to write it, I suggested adding a paragraph saying what to do.

Comment: I understand, but the question was not asking how to build a carousel.